# Chain and Product Rule Problem

Tags: calculus

Find $$\frac{d}{dx}\left\{x^3(2x-5)^4\right\}.$$ I have been working on this problem for a few hours and I cannot figure it out. I would appreciate any guidance on it.

Comment: I assume you want to take the derivative? If so, can you share what you've tried? Perhaps we can point out a mistake, if there is one.

Comment: What @T.Bongers said. After all, you are completely indicating exactly how to do the problem in the title you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let $h(x)=f(x) g(x)$.  Then the product rule says that

$$h'(x)=f'(x) g(x)+f(x) g'(x).$$

Take $f(x)=x^3$ and $g(x)=(2x-5)^4$.  For $g(x)$ you need to use the chain rule.  Let $g(x)=a(b(x))$ with $b(x)=2x-5$ and $a(y)=y^4$.  Then the chain rule says that

$$g'(x) = a'(b(x)) b'(x).$$

I'm confident that you can figure out the derivatives of $f,a,b$ and plug them in to the above expressions to obtain the final result!

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left\{x^3(2x-5)^4\right\}\\
=(2x-5)^4\frac{d}{dx}\left\{x^3\right\}+x^3\frac{d}{dx}\left\{(2x-5)^4\right\}\\
=(2x-5)^43x^2+x^3\frac{d}{d(2x-5)}\left\{(2x-5)^4\right\}\cdot 2\\
=(2x-5)^43x^2+8x^3(2x-5)^3=(2x-5)^43x^2+8(x(2x-5))^3$$