# Using the Chain Rule and Product Rule

Tags: calculus

Find $dy/dx: y=x^3(2x-5)^4$.

I have been working on this problem for a few hours. I get the problem to 
$$y'=x^3*(4)*(2x-5)^3*(2)+(2x-5)^4*(3x)^2$$
 but then I do not know what to do next. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chain and Product Rule Problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699801/chain-and-product-rule-problem)

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks right EXCEPT for the last bit of your expression, where you have (accidentally) included $3$ in the power of $2$.

The correct expression should be:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y'=x^3(4)(2x-5)^3(2)+(2x-5)^4(3)x^2 .$$

Comment: One **could** multiply some numerical factors together, collect like terms, take out some common factors and get (I think)  $x^2(2x-5)^3(14x-15)$ but it's not a better answer, just different looking...